# Redirect react router dom auth not working

Tags: reactjs, redux

It does not fail to redirect to a battery page after login, because a route thinks it has no token in the header there it blocks. I'm trying more than two days, please some good soul. All the logic of the back end is already working perfectly. It is not possible to substitute a path for the user to log on and generate the token. The system redirects it to a battery route

Login class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import IntanceAxios from '../../components/meuaxios'
// import GlobalStyle from './style.jsx';
import Form from './Form.jsx'
import { /* useSelector, useDispatch ,*/ connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import history from '../../routes/History';

class Login extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            email: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isRememberUser')) ? localStorage.getItem('user') : undefined,
            password: undefined,
            signIn: {
                success: undefined,
                message: undefined,
                load: undefined,
                type_error: 'error'
            },
            fieldErrors: {
                email: {
                    message: '',
                    isValid: true
                },
                password: {
                    message: '',
                    isValid: true
                }
            },
            logged: false,
            loadedOne: true
        }
        document.title = "Login"
    }

    // Initialization
    componentWillMount() {
        let isRememberUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isRememberUser'))

        if (isRememberUser && localStorage.getItem('user') === null) {
            localStorage.removeItem('isRememberUser')
        }
    }

    // Monteded
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            loadedOne: false
        })
    }

    validEmail = email => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape
        const validEmailRegex = RegExp(/^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i);
        return validEmailRegex.test(email)
    }

    handleEmailChange(e) {
        var value = e.target.value

        let fieldEmail = this.validEmail(value) ? true : false;

        let message = fieldEmail ? '' : 'Email esta inválido'

        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                email: value,
                fieldErrors: {
                    email: {
                        message: message,
                        isValid: fieldEmail
                    },
                    password: {
                        message: prevState.fieldErrors.password.message,
                        isValid: prevState.fieldErrors.password.isValid
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    handlePasswordChange(e) {
        var value = e.target.value
        let fieldPassoword =
            value.length < 8 ? false : true;

        let message = fieldPassoword ? '' : 'A senha deve conter mais de 8 caracteres!'
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                password: value,
                fieldErrors: {
                    password: {
                        message: message,
                        isValid: fieldPassoword
                    },
                    email: {
                        message: prevState.fieldErrors.email.message,
                        isValid: prevState.fieldErrors.email.isValid
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    isValid() {
        let { email, password } = this.state.fieldErrors
        if (email.isValid && password.isValid) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    setUserRemember = () => {
        if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isRememberUser'))) {
            localStorage.setItem('user', this.state.email)
        }
        return;
    }

    setToken = token => {
        return localStorage.setItem('ISA)_TOKEN', token);
    }

    async handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (!this.state.email || this.state.email === undefined || this.state.password === undefined || !this.state.password) {

            this.setState(prevState => {
                return {
                    ...this.state,
                    signIn: {
                        message: 'E-mail ou senha vazio',
                        success: false,
                        type_error: 'error'
                    }, logged: false,

                    fieldErrors: {
                        password: {
                            message: prevState.fieldErrors.password.message,
                            isValid: false
                        },
                        email: {
                            message: prevState.fieldErrors.email.message,
                            isValid: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            return null;
        }

        if (this.isValid()) {

            this.setUserRemember();
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                signIn: {
                    load: true,
                    success: undefined,
                    type_error: undefined
                }
            });

            // console.log(dataToSend);
            let dataToSend = {
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password
            }
            let url = '/auth/login';

            await IntanceAxios.post(url, dataToSend)
                .then(response => response.data)
                .then(responseData => {

                    if (responseData.success) {

                        // this.props.disparaLogin();
                        // this.props.verificarToken();
                        this.setToken(responseData.token)

                        this.setState({
                            ...this.state,
                            signIn: {
                                success: true,
                                message: responseData.message,
                            }, logged: true
                            , status: true
                        });
                        let { from } = this.props.location || { from: { pathname: "/batteries" } };
                        console.log(from)
                        history.replace(from)
                        // history.replace(from);

                        // REDIRECIONA PARA O LOCAL RAIZ, FEITO NA UNHA
                        // this.setState({ redirectToReferrer: true });
                    } else {

                        this.setState({
                            ...this.state,
                            signIn: {
                                success: false,
                                message: responseData.message,
                                type_error: 'error'

                            }, status: false
                            , logged: false,
                        })
                    }

                }).catch(error => {
                    this.removeRember();
                    this.setState({
                        ...this.state,
                        signIn: {
                            success: false,
                            message: error.message,
                            type_error: 'error'

                        }, status: false
                        , logged: false,
                    });
                    console.log(error);
                });
        } else {
            this.removeRember()

            return;

        }

    }

    removeRember = () => {
        if (localStorage.getItem('user') !== null) {
            localStorage.removeItem('user')
            localStorage.setItem('isRememberUser', false)
        }
        return;
    }


    render() {
        const { signIn, fieldErrors, email, password, loadedOne } = this.state
        return (
            <>
                {/* <Header /> */}
                {/* <GlobalStyle /> */}
                <Form loadedOne={loadedOne} signIn={signIn} email={email} password={password} fieldErrors={fieldErrors} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind()} handleEmailChange={this.handleEmailChange.bind()} handlePasswordChange={this.handlePasswordChange.bind()} />
            </>
        )
    }
}

// export default Login;

const mapearAcoes = dispatch => {
    return {
        disparaLogin: () => dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN' }),
        verificarToken: () => dispatch({ type: 'vericarToken' })
    }
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

Routes

```
import React from 'react';

// Controllers 
import Login from '../views/Login/Login.jsx';
import Register from '../views/Register/Register.jsx';
import Logout from '../views/Logout/Logout.jsx';
import MapRealtime from '../views/MapRealtime/MapRealtime.jsx';
import DashBoardBaterry from '../views/DashBoardBaterry/DashBoardBaterry.jsx';

// import Painel from '../views/Painel/Painel.jsx';

// Autenthenticated of user
import { isAuthenticated } from '../components/auth.jsx';
// package of routes
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
// import { Router, hashHistory } from 'react-router';

// Response of validation of key token
const responseIsAuthenticated = isAuthenticated();

// Verify if user to be logged and permited access some outhers pages, case otherwise redirection for the login 
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route  {...rest} render={props => (
        responseIsAuthenticated ? (
            <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
                <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }} />
            )
    )} />
)

alert(responseIsAuthenticated)

// Verify if user to be logged and redirection for the APP
const Authenticated = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        responseIsAuthenticated ? (
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/batteries", state: { from: props.location } }} />

        ) : (
                <Component {...props} />
            )
    )} />
)

const Routes = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={() => <h1>Home page</h1>} />
            <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/maprealtime" component={MapRealtime} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/batteries" component={DashBoardBaterry} />
            {/* <PrivateRoute path="/account" component={() => <h1>Account</h1>} /> */}
            <PrivateRoute path="/app" component={() => <h1>Autenticado</h1>} />
            <Authenticated exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Authenticated exact path="/registrar" component={Register} />
            <Route path="/not-authorized" component={() => <h1>Pagina não autorizada</h1>} />

            {/* This route want be a last */}
            <Route path="*" component={() => <h1>NotFound</h1>} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>

);

export default (Routes);
```

App

```
import React from 'react';
// import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Routes from './routes/Routes.jsx';
import store from './store/reducer';

// Verifyted of internet 
import NetworkDetector from './components/NetworkDetector.jsx'

import { ThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { blue } from '@material-ui/core/colors';

import './assets/vendor/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './assets/css/main.css';


const defaultTheme = createMuiTheme();


const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#2194f3',
      main: '#2194f3',
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#4B4B4D',
      main: '#666668',
    },
    colorPrimary: {
      light: '#63b4f6',
      main: '#2194f3',
    },
    colorSecondary: {
      light: '#fbe53d',
      main: '#fff079',
    },
    colorDefault: '#2194f3',
  },
  formControl: {
    color: blue
  },
  spacingLi: {
    paddingLeft: defaultTheme.spacing(4),
  }

});

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Routes />
      </ThemeProvider >
    </Provider>

  );
}

export default NetworkDetector(App);
```

Auth user

```
export const isAuthenticated = () => {
    // let autheticated = false;
    let token = localStorage.getItem('ISA)_TOKEN');

    if (!token) {
        // this.redirectToReferrer(false);
        // let autheticated = false

        return false

    } else {

        let url = 'http://localhost:5000/auth/verifytoken ';
        fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            body: undefined,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(responseData => {
                if (!responseData.success) {
                    localStorage.removeItem('ISA)_TOKEN');
                    window.location.replace('/')
                    return null;
                }

                // this.redirectToReferrer(true);


            }).catch(error => {
                localStorage.removeItem('ISA)_TOKEN');
                window.location.replace('/')
            });



        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above triggers an additional (non related) warning by attempting to "Changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled". To fix this, switch `FormComponent` to a [Controlled strategy](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), use the component state to manage the input values and validation, and just bind as prop the required methods to handle a login request or some async validation.

Related to the autentication problem, it seems to occur because when application loads, the `Router` module, already sets the `responseIsAuthenticated` value, evaluating the token state ahead of time. To ensure always evaluate the current state, you must call to the `isAuthenticated` method inside your `render` prop:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route  {...rest} render={props => (
        // Call to isAuthenticated here.
        isAuthenticated() ? (
            <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
                <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }} />
            )
    )} />
)
```

Also, in order to redirect the user after a successful login. I would recommend attach a `Redirect` component in "LoginComponent":

```
render() {
    const { signIn, fieldErrors, email, password, loadedOne } = this.state

    if(signIn.success)
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/batteries"}} />;

    /* <Form /> */
```

Comment: I love you man rsrs, you solved my problem. Much thank. answered my question very fast, thank you.